# curl: (60) server certificate verification failed

Tags: ubuntu, php, curl

I am getting this error message when I try to use `curl` on Ubuntu 16.04:

> curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile:
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

I have downloaded cacert.pem and put the path to it in php.ini and set env variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` but it still fails.

> curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile:
>   /var/www/cacert/cacert.pem CRLfile: none

I can view the site I am trying to curl from and it give no SSL errors and the cert is issued by GoDaddy.

I need curl in a PHP application where I can’t change the code (WordPress plugin) so using `-k` or `--insecure` doesn't help as I can't modify calling code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after changing `php.ini`? Have you checked the output of `phpinfo()` to make sure you changed the *right* `php.ini` (many installations have more than one)?

Comment: Yes, also on the second error message it outputs the path to the cacert.pem file I downloaded.

Comment: And you're certain you have the latest version of https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem (Wed Jan 18 04:12:05 2017 GMT)? What domain name are you cURLing?

Comment: yep, downloaded from that url today.  Domain name is zanedo.com (I am downloading images)

Comment: I just restarted again and now I can use it on command line but not in the application still. phpinfo() shows curl enabled but doesn't show curl.cainfo path, not sure if its meant to?